# Why did my snake die suddenly?

Tags: snakes, death

My boyfriend and I had a ball python and we loved him very much. He was only a couple years old. He was perfectly fine last night, but in the morning he was limp and one of his sides turned grey. I tried googling and googling, but nothing came up about why he was turning grey. He died and we are very upset and have no idea what went wrong. Please help.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about its environment? Also there was any sudden change in weather conditions?

Comment: Was the Ball Python skin wrinkly?

Answer (score -3):

Hi there jxzzx and welcome to Pets.SE. There are many reasons why your ball python could have died. Here is a list of them:

Dehydration: Symptoms include Wrinkly Skin, Lack of appetite, constipation, Rapid weight Loss, and stuck shed around eyes, tail, and nose.

Low/High Cage temperature

Infection

and parasitism.

I am very sorry for your loss.